# React-Native Item Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to select an item from a list and to highlight it. I got a function on how to delete a particular item from the array, i want to reuse this function to highlight it.

Data is an array of objects. I want to use hooks to manage state. id is asigned to every item in the array. I want to presshandler function as property for onPress.

```
const [selected, setSelect] = useState(Data);

const presshandler = (id) => {
    setSelect((prev) => {
        return prev.filter((list) => list.id !== id);
    });
};
```

Comment: so what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Well, i been trying to figure out how to select an item from flat list and store it at the state. I can't seem to find any examples online, especially using hooks. All I want to be able to select and unselect a particular element.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to set `highlighted` to `true` after you press an image:

```
const toggleSelect = id => {
    setSelect(prev => {
        return prev.map(item => {
            if(item.id !== id) return item
            return {
                ...item,
                highlighted: !item.highlighted
            }
        })
    })
}
// Usage:
<Image onPress={() => toggleSelect(image.id)} {...rest} />
```

After reading your comment, I see you want a toggle. So I edited my example.

Comment: Thanks so much, its working. I been struggling so much with it.